# Curl works, but not pages in a web browser with OpenLiteSpeed

Tags: networking, ssh, ufw

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a Linode server and OpenLiteSpeed `openlitespeed.org`.

I'm getting timeouts for `example.com:8088` and `example.com:7080`, the two OpenLiteSpeed admin and config pages, in a browser.

But while logged in via SSH, running
`curl 127.0.0.1`
gives me the text of the index.html file at root, and
`curl http://localhost:8088`
gives me the html dump of the OpenLiteSpeed admin page.

From another host, running `curl 123.45.67.123` works.

Going directly to the site/server IP `123.45.67.123` works.

From another host, running `curl example` *does not return anything*.

Going to `example.com` in a browser works and shows me the index.html page.

Pinging `example.com` works.

But I can't connect to `example.com:8088` or `example.com:7080` in a browser.

Apache is running, but OpenLiteSpeed hasn't yet been configured to use port 80, since I can't get to the admin pages.

ufw status shows:

```
65500                ALLOW        Anywhere                 
443                    ALLOW        Anywhere                 
443/tcp                ALLOW        Anywhere                 
7080/tcp            ALLOW        Anywhere                 
8088/tcp            ALLOW        Anywhere                 
OpenSSH        ALLOW        Anywhere                 
80/tcp                ALLOW        Anywhere                 
65500 (v6)        ALLOW        Anywhere (v6)            
443 (v6)            ALLOW        Anywhere (v6)            
443/tcp (v6)        ALLOW        Anywhere (v6)            
7080/tcp (v6)    ALLOW        Anywhere (v6)            
8088/tcp (v6)    ALLOW        Anywhere (v6)            
OpenSSH (v6)    ALLOW        Anywhere (v6)            
80/tcp (v6)        ALLOW        Anywhere (v6)
```

Completely disabling ufw makes no difference with the issue.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit 10/25/2020:**

[image]

---

**Edit 10/26/2020**

This worked from my local Mac with port 7080 denied in `ufw` on the server and brings up the OLS admin page:

`ssh -L 7080:123.45.67.123:7080 root@123.45.67.123`

Important note: I was using CloudFlare, which was part of the problem. CloudFlare blocks port 7080 (as well as others; see https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Identifying-network-ports-compatible-with-Cloudflare-s-proxy ). So in order to use the localhost tunnel as Carles Mateo's answer, you need to change OpenLiteSpeed's admin port to an allowed CloudFlare port (like 8443) in /usr/local`/lsws/admin/conf/admin_config.conf`, restart OpenLiteSpeed. And also disable any SSLs at CloudFlare, at least until you configure an SSL that doesn't throw security errors.

Overall, my solution to protect the OpenLiteSpeed admin page from script kiddies, etc., while using CloudFlare is to change to and use port 8443 to configure OLS settings, and then via SSH change that port back to 7080, which is blocked by default by CloudFlare.

Comment: Are you attempting to reach example.com from another host or just the server? Does the server and clients all know who example.com is? can you ping example.com? Do you get the same results if you use the server's IP address?

Comment: @WU-TANG Thanks, I added more details in my question.

Comment: Hi, my eyes are a little lost... can you separate the two groups of info by something like "from server" and "from client"... in the meantime.... is there any admin group that the user needs to be a part of to hit those admin pages? does netstat -tl (or ss -tl) show that the ports are listening to everyone not just locally or one host?

Comment: This seems like two issues, one: a DNS issue. `curl example` can't return anything if your DNS entry is `example.com` unless your search domain includes `com` . Also `curl` will default to Port 80, so you cannot compare `curl example.com` to opening `example.com:8088` in the browser. Which brings me to the second issue: is the service even listening on 8088 and 7080 ? You can check this with `netstat -tulpen` and make sure the local adress is either your IP or 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1. If its just 127.0.0.1 then you can only access it from the host.

Comment: @RobertRiedl Thanks, I added netstat output, but I'm not clear on how to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is that OpenLiteSpeed is only listening on localhost address.

Please make sure that is listening for 0.0.0.0, which means all the addresses. In my sample there are processes listening on 127.0.0.1 and processes listening on all the ip's in IPV4 0.0.0.0 and IPV6 :::

```
carles@fast:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
[sudo] password for carles: 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      45335/java          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41601         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      45335/java          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      45335/java          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      827/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1143/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      455095/cupsd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34585         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      160123/java         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2072/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43195         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      160123/java         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1143/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      455095/cupsd        
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      2072/master
```

If you want to debug if traffic gets from other sites, run tcpdump on the Server and attempt to connect from another machine. You'll see if there is that attempt.
Please check this before and provide an answer to continue debugging.

But whatever your connectivity problem is you can get to the localhost:8088 from your browser using a tunnel.

If you use Ubuntu as your Desktop you can do:

```
ssh -L LOCAL_PORT:DESTINATION:DESTINATION_PORT [USER@]SSH_SERVER
```

For example:

```
ssh -L 8088:123.45.67.89:8080 [USER@]123.45.67.89
```

Then in your browser you just connect to localhost:8088 and the tunnel will make the magic and your Server will believe that the connection is made local, so you can configure anything from your browser.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, same issue with ssh: `Bad local forwarding specification 8088:localhost:example.com:8088`. netstat output added.

Comment: remove the localhost. So 8088:example.com:8088. If you want to use it the is localhost:8088:example.com:8088.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the OpenLightSpeed admin page: `ssh -L 7080:123.45.67.123 :7080 root@123.45.67.123` with port 7080 denied in `ufw`. I had to use the IP rather than the domain. I also added more details in my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advice you NOT to open these ports. Instead do the following.

Connect to your server with your outside machine via SSH and create an encrypted tunnel just for you. Type the following in your terminal and you will be able to browse your desired webpages.

Open a terminal on your local machine with ssh.

```
ssh -L 8088:example.com:8088 user@example.com
```

As long as you keep this terminal open, you can now browse the desired page with.
https://localhost:8088

and yes your browser will be terrified that this certificate is wrong, just click continue and you are all set.

Repeat this with the other port. Or if you use Windows use putty and check the ssl options. WSL2 also works for me.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense for security, but your ssh example gives me `Bad local forwarding specification 8088:localhost:example.com:8088`

Comment: As s1mmel comments, admin ports should not be open to worldwide. Even if you add firewall rules if one day the firewall is stopped or you change it inadvertently you would be exposed to be hacked.